# Trusted traveler login change: How do I find out the status of my pending Global Entry application?

Tags: us-citizens, global-entry

I applied for a Global Entry ID last week, and I want to know how to find out the status of the application.

I applied around September 27th, including paying the application fee. I've been revisiting the GOES site periodically to see what the status is. It turns out that as of today, October 1st, if you go to the GOES site it redirects to a login.gov URL and there doesn't seem to be a way to complete the workflow and get back to the state I was in before. That is to say, I can't find my application status.

I have started to fill in a new profile using login.gov to get access, but it wants a number called PASS ID that seems to be in fact the number you'd get at the end (after application review and interview). So again how do I find out the status of my application now that the access/login method has changed so radically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My question was how to find out the PASS ID if one hadn't written it down off the screen as Berwyn said.

I write this answer to point out the resolution that may apply to others in my position. I am sure this info is in the comments I've posted.

They created a system after October 1st to enable people to use their GOES ID, which is not a PASS ID, to recover their PASS ID's from the "old" system and proceed with their applications. It is mentioned at login.gov.

You don't need to be lucky enough to have the PASS ID in the browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

Your PASS ID is your GOES membership number and is assigned at the beiginning of your application. It will subsequently be your Known Traveller Number (KTN) for the purposes of TSA Pre Check.

I believe GOES is transitioning to this new site: https://ttp.cbp.dhs.gov/

Comment: Second thing first: The subject of this question is basically the transition from the old GOES to the new TTP with login.gov handling the log in.

Comment: There was nothing that I saw that said I needed to remember a number as such when I got to the point where I paid the fee. And now since I cannot get access to the status I can't tell what number I would have got, if the number is assigned before the fee is paid.

Comment: @cardiffspaceman I received my GOES PASS ID when I paid the fee, which I noted at that time. In reviewing my emails, they didn't ever send that information out in any email, you had to login to get it. They sent me a login User ID in email. Did you receive that? Have you tried that on ttp and it doesn't work?

Comment: You have to make a new login the first time it sends you to login.gov.

Comment: I found the number in the Google Chrome cache and added it to my "TTP" profile. and now I can see my status. It seems like it should have been easier.

Comment: @cardiffspaceman That does seem like an ordeal. Glad you solved it and good luck with the application. I found GE worth its weight in gold

Comment: I have learned that the nice people administering the program are aware that many people have had trouble, due to the sudden switchover to login.gov. I used a form to ask about this and the canned response was that they are building a migration method that works if you still remember  your GOES login name and another piece of information. Also if you call the right CSRs they can find your PASS ID for you. I'm not sure how much of this information is "answer quality"

Comment: Sort of tangential to my original question, the canned email I mentioned in the recent comment also states that if you don't have your PASS-ID but you do have an interview scheduled, just go to the interview and the nice interviewer will help you out.